# Can we use an adverb together with nouns?

Tags: grammar, adverb-position

i know that the preposition can be used with nouns.

For example : 
              skin **between** your ......

```
          connection between.......

          the girl after you......

          the car before the other ones...
```

So, can we say  '' The man ***here*** '' ???

if we can , would you please give an example ? Thank you...

Comment: I would take it as an intransitive preposition. In, for example, "The man here is my father", the intransitive preposition "here" is used locatively and probably deictically, and is functioning as an adjunct.

Answer (score 3):

Adverbs can usually only modify verbs or adjectives. But some words are both adverbs and adjectives.

For example, the word "fast" is both. "The fast man ran fast."

The word "quick" is an adjective, but can be made into an adverb by adding -ly. "The quick man ran quickly." But it would sound wrong to say "The quickly man ran quickly."

Most dictionaries seem to give the word "here" as an adverb, but with special uses. In phrases like "come here" you can see why that is. In phrases like "here we are" or "the man here," there's an argument that actually it's working as an adjective, but an adjective which goes after the noun, which is unusual in English.

Most adverbs though? It would sound strange unless they are also adjectives already.